# Commentaries on Moreh Nevuchim

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, commentaries, moreh-nevuchim

I have heard that there are many commentaries on Moreh Nevuchim. However, all editions that I have seen in person contain just the text, sometimes with editorial footnotes. Can anyone provide:

**1) A list of classical commentaries**

**2) If possible, a place to find them online**

Thank you

Comment: Note, I am aware of this question, but am looking for a list of commentaries and where to find them online:https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33386/which-published-moreh-nevuchim-would-you-recommend

Comment: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/14118

Comment: See [this quip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RWHR.png).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A friend of mine compiled the following list:

This edition: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/14118 has [**Efodi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiat_Duran), [**Shem Tov ibn Shem Tov**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shem_Tov_ibn_Shem_Tov), [**ibn Crescas**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasdai_Crescas), and [**Abarbanel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Abarbanel).

This: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/31594 is the commentary of [**R. Moshe Narboni**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Joshua).

This is the commentary of [**R. Shem Tov ibn Falaquera**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shem-Tov_ibn_Falaquera): https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/23920.

Two commentaries by [**R. Yosef ibn Caspi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Caspi) are found here: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/34446.

Sisrei Torah of [**R. Avraham Abulafia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Abulafia) is found here: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/49764.

That's a total of 9 commentaries.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your excellent answer. If you don't mind, I have 3 followup questions:

Comment: 1) In the first link, the Abarbanel appears to comment very sporadically, and then at the end of the book there are several pages of just abarbanel. Did he write two seperate works, or is the commentary just oddly laid out?

Comment: 2) While R Abulafia wrote 3 commentaries, the link you provided seems to only include one of them. Am I missing something?

Comment: 3) are you aware of any edition of Abarbanel still in print?

Comment: Sorry was mistaken about R Abulafia. Regarding the Abarbanel, I'm not so familiar so I can't answer. For what it's worth, there's a not in print version of his commentary without the others: https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/30671